# NULLIF of FINAL SUM Doubled when using MATCH_RECOGNIZE

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, nullif, match-recognize

When I run the following code, I would expect `b1` and `b2` to be equal, however, `b2` is doubled. Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug in the database? We're running `Oracle 12c` `(12.2.0.1.0)`.

```
WITH TBL AS
  (
  SELECT 1 a, 1 b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 a, 2 b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 a, 3 b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 a, 4 b FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT
  *
FROM
  TBL
MATCH_RECOGNIZE
  (
  PARTITION BY
    a
  ORDER BY
    b
  MEASURES
    FINAL SUM(b) b1,
    NULLIF(FINAL SUM(b), 0) b2
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH WITH UNMATCHED ROWS
  AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
  PATTERN
    (C*)
  DEFINE
    C AS B > 0
  ) mr
```

Result:

```
| A | B | B1 | B2 |
|---|---|----|----|
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 20 |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | 20 |
| 1 | 3 | 10 | 20 |
| 1 | 4 | 10 | 20 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with `NULLIF` when I converted the same into it's logical equivalent and it is working fine `CASE WHEN expr1 = expr 2 THEN NULL ELSE expr1 END`

```
WITH TBL AS
      (
      SELECT 1 a, 1 b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 a, 2 b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 a, 3 b FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 a, 4 b FROM DUAL
      )
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      TBL
    MATCH_RECOGNIZE
      (
      PARTITION BY
        a
      ORDER BY
        b
      MEASURES
        FINAL SUM(b) b1,
       CASE WHEN FINAL SUM(b)=0 THEN NULL ELSE FINAL SUM(b) END b2
      ALL ROWS PER MATCH WITH UNMATCHED ROWS
      AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
      PATTERN
        (C*)
      DEFINE
        C AS B > 0
      ) mr
```

Result

```
    | A | B | B1 | B2 |
    |---|---|----|----|
    | 1 | 1 | 10 | 10 |
    | 1 | 2 | 10 | 10 |
    | 1 | 3 | 10 | 10 |
    | 1 | 4 | 10 | 10 |
```

Comment: Agreed, I think there is a bug in `NULLIF` when combined with `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`.

Comment: Is there a way to submit bugs to Oracle?

Comment: You need to ask your DBA to submit a support ticket in oracle @ support.oracle.com